# Deleting a value from address to address mapping in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-classic

```
mapping(address => address) public userpatient;
```

I want to delete a the key value pair from above map,when the patient is discharged.How can i do it.I saw similar question here but it mentioned 'delete' identifier which is not working

Comment: `delete userpatient[key]` or `userpatient[key] = address(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Is `address` a struct?

Like user goodvibration has said, `delete userpatient[key]` would work, but since you're tagging `ethereum-classic`, I would like to know what version of Solidity you're running.

ETC functions with version 0.4.20 or lower due to missing OP-Codes that need to be hardforked in. 0.4.21 or higher is incompatible with Ethereum Classic.